# how can I maintain a GWT1.7.1 application if I already have the new google eclipse plugin?

Tags: gwt, eclipse-plugin

I have a GWT 1.7.1 application. I recently recreated my eclipse with the new google eclipse plugin. When I try to run the hosted mode the browser tries to connect to the google browser plugin page and tries to install the IE plugin into the hosted mode browser.

It seems like it is mixing the GWT2 tech with the old project. Is there a solution for this? Is it possible to still download the old eclipse plugin somewhere? Would this solve my problem?

Comment: I am voting to close my question. The question is based on the false premise that the new plugin can't support the old GWT, but it can.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in Eclipse when installing a plugin, there is an option to see older version of a plugin (they are hidden by default).  This might help you find a version of it that you can use.  I'm guessing if you uninstall the current version, try to add in the GWT plugin again but choose the 1.7.1 version, you should be good to go.  Newer versions of Eclipse also keep snapshots of your plugin setup in case you want to revert back, so you might look at that too if you know you had the 1.7.1 version at one point.  Hopefully one of those helps you out.

Side note: Then if you need to develop for GWT 2 and GWT 1.7.1 simultaneously and want to use Eclipse for both, one solution is to use two copies of Eclipse.  Eclipse is good about allowing for multiple installs.  I'm sure there are reasons this is a bad idea, but it will work.

Comment: These are good suggestions, but it doesn't seem like Google provides the old plugins. I hosed my old eclipse, so I don't have the previous version anymore either

Answer (score 0):

Found this:
If you want to use the plugin, and have the development mode window show up instead of Eclipse's development mode view, set the "USE_REMOTE_UI" environment variable FOR YOUR LAUNCH CONFIGURATION to the value "false".

From here:
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/TroubleshootingOOPHM

Worked like a charm for me.